# WPF TabControl with MVVM using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm very new to WPF but quite experienced with .NET and C#. I am trying to create (what I though would be) a fairly simple CRUD admin desktop application for a website I plan on building.

WPF seems to be way more complicated than I expected it to be and after lots of Googling I've basically realised that everyone uses the MVVM pattern - fine. Now, with my existing .NET experience, I know I definitely want to to be using dependency injection. I've discovered that everything seems to be done within the ViewModel in WPF, including all the services and everything - fine again.

Now, onto my problem. I have set up a basic tab control and I'm binding the tab values to an enum using `Enum.GetValues()`. I want the view to change when I select a tab and the view will depend on which tab is selected. The problem is, I can't seem to get the view to show - it just shows a blank screen. The view is a custom UserControl I've created and defined as a resource and contains a grid and a bunch of buttons and stuff. I've omitted this from below as it doesn't seem relevant.

My **MainWindow.xaml** is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Stc.Admin.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Stc.Admin.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Stc.Admin.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stc.Admin"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTab}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:GamesViewModel}">
                    <views:Games />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding DataContext.CurrentViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's my **MainViewModel.cs**:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IViewModelFactory<GamesViewModel> _gamesViewModelFactory;

    private ViewType _currentTab;
    public ViewType CurrentTab
    { 
        get
        {
            return _currentTab;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentTab = value;
            ChangeView(_currentTab);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ViewType> Tabs { get; }
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(IViewModelFactory<GamesViewModel> gamesViewModelFactory)
    {
        _gamesViewModelFactory = gamesViewModelFactory;

        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ViewType>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ViewType)).Cast<ViewType>().ToArray());
    }

    private void ChangeView(ViewType viewType)
    {
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case ViewType.Games:
                CurrentViewModel = _gamesViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel();
                break;
            case ViewType.Listings:
                break;
            case ViewType.Users:
                break;
            case ViewType.Languages:
                break;
            case ViewType.Currencies:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum ViewType
{
    Games,
    Listings,
    Users,
    Languages,
    Currencies
}
```

`GamesViewModel` has service dependencies so it needs to be created using the factory.

And my DI setup in **App.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = this.createServiceProvider();

        Window window = new MainWindow();
        window.DataContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
        window.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private IServiceProvider createServiceProvider()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDbContext<StcContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Stc;Integrated Security=True"));

        services.AddSingleton<ICrudService<Game>, CrudService<Game>>();

        services.AddSingleton<IViewModelFactory<GamesViewModel>, GamesViewModelFactory>();

        services.AddScoped<MainViewModel>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this issue now. Being new to WPF, I didn't realise that I have to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to get the UI to update after changing a property value on my ViewModel. I'd seen this used in a lot of the articles and tutorials I was seeing but didn't really understand what it was or how to apply it to my application.

The change I made was to implement this interface on my base ViewModel like so:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I then change my **MainViewModel** to inherit from the base class and changed the setter of the `CurrentTab` property to call `OnPropertyChanged` (with the name of the property) after I've changed the view/viewmodel property:

```
private ViewType _currentTab;
public ViewType CurrentTab
{ 
    get
    {
        return _currentTab;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentTab = value;
        ChangeView(_currentTab);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel));
    }
}
```

I believe this is telling the UI that something has changed and it needs to redraw itself. Correct me if I'm wrong or if that's an oversimplification.